# change UIButton title without fade effect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

When I change the title of a UIButton it has this effect where the old title fades out and the new one fades in. Can I change the title without the animation?

```
[self.a setTitle:@"a" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

For system `UIButton`, using:

```
[self.a layoutIfNeeded];
```

For custom `UIButton`, using:

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
[self.a setTitle:@"a" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to do this

1.System Button without animation

```
- (IBAction)actionChangeButtonTitle:(id)sender
{
  [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
  [buttonTitleChange setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
  [buttonTitleChange layoutIfNeeded]; //For System Buttons
}
```

2.Custom Button Without animation

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn addTarget:self 
       action:@selector(actionChangeButtonTitle:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn setTitle:@"Change Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:btn];
- (IBAction)actionChangeButtonTitle:(id)sender
{
  [btn setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Thank You-:)